# Zooming an image while keeping it centered in SDL2

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d, zooming, sdl-2

I'm trying to use this code to zoom images in SDL2. I want the image to stay centered while zooming, but I can't seem to figure it out (I've tried several methods, and this one looks the best so far... but that's not saying much)

```
void Image::drawFlat(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y, float scaleWidth, float scaleHeight) {
    if(this->position.x != x || this->position.y != y || this->scaleWidth != scaleWidth || this->scaleHeight != scaleHeight) {
        SDL_QueryTexture(this->imageCache, NULL, NULL, &this->position.w, &this->position.h);
        this->position.x = (int) x - (this->position.w * scaleWidth + this->position.w) / 2;
        this->position.y = (int) y - (this->position.h * scaleHeight + this->position.h) / 2;
        this->position.w = (int) this->position.w * scaleWidth;
        this->position.h = (int) this->position.h * scaleHeight;
        this->scaleWidth = scaleWidth;
        this->scaleHeight = scaleHeight;
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, this->imageCache, NULL, &this->position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to reverse two signs:

```
void Image::drawFlat(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y, float scaleWidth, float scaleHeight) {
    if(this->position.x != x || this->position.y != y || this->scaleWidth != scaleWidth || this->scaleHeight != scaleHeight) {
        SDL_QueryTexture(this->imageCache, NULL, NULL, &this->position.w, &this->position.h);
        this->position.x = (int) x - (this->position.w * scaleWidth - this->position.w) / 2;
        this->position.y = (int) y - (this->position.h * scaleHeight - this->position.h) / 2;
        this->position.w = (int) this->position.w * scaleWidth;
        this->position.h = (int) this->position.h * scaleHeight;
        this->scaleWidth = scaleWidth;
        this->scaleHeight = scaleHeight;
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, this->imageCache, NULL, &this->position);
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u5fKd/) (use arrows to move, numpad + and - for width scaling, [ and ] for height scaling)